# After adding a drop shadow to a list cell hovering and selection events are bugged

Tags: javafx, hover, javafx-css

So I added the below fx-css to a `list-cell`.

```
.list-cell:selected:filled:hover {
    -fx-view-order: -1;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, #67676D, 12, 0.05, 0.0, 2);
}
```

Note when a list-cell is `:selected` its background is grey.

Now it seems the node boundaries are extended to the end of the drop shadow over the surrounding cells. This behavior is unwanted as the cell with the shadow captures events that should really be handled by the below or above cell.

[image]

Is there a fix for this?

Note: the same fx-css can be applied to a `table-view` and this unwanted functionally does not occur.

```
public class ListViewTest {
    @Test
    public void testFx() throws InterruptedException {
        new JFXPanel();
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            ListView<String> lv =  new ListView<>();

            lv.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<>() {

                {
                    setPrefHeight(38);
                    hoverProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                            if (newValue) {
                                setStyle("""
                                    -fx-view-order: -1;
                                    -fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, #67676D, 12, 0.05, 0.0, 2);
                                """);
                            } else {
                                setStyle(null);
                            }
                        });
                }

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (empty || item == null) {

                    } else {

                    }
                }
            });
            var items = FXCollections.observableArrayList("1", "2", "3");
            lv.setItems(items);
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            Scene scene = new Scene(lv);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        });
        latch.await();
    }
}
```

Comment: worksforme (current dev fx16++, didn't try earlier versions), so might be something wrong in your context, as always [mcve] please ;) btw: your cell implementation is wrong in registering a new hover listener on each call.

Comment: @kleopatra ah yes moved hover listener to constructor. hmm ill try the newest version of fx later today.   I figured a test was a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: hmm, the test is not what produced the image, or is it? But didn't look into TestFX for a while .. :) Strictly speaking, a test is not stand-alone because it requires the test lib - personally, would draw the line at junit. Anyway, my reason for suggesting a real example was the worksforme (taking your cell into an app), so suspected something wrong outside of the code you are showing here

Comment: @kleopatra Problem occurs for me on FX 15. Interestingly, as noted by OP, this problem doesn't seem to occur for `.table-row-cell:selected:filled:hover: { ... }`. It's like the drop shadow is included in the bounds of the list cell but not the table row. **Edit:** Only difference I can find is `TableRowSkinBase` calls `getSkinnable().setPickOnBounds(false);`.

Comment: @Slaw that's weird - don't see any problem .. and don't remember any change between 15 and 16+ that might be relevant here

Comment: hmm .. re-reading the question: might have misunderstood, will check again tomorrow

Comment: @kleopatra. This is actually just junit, by chance the method is just called textfx =).  I understand the valid point your saying though.

Comment: darn, must have been sleeping - thanks for waking me up :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your note:

> Note: the same fx-css can be applied to a table-view and this unwanted functionally does not occur.

I assume you're applying the style to the table *rows* and not the table *cells*. I'm making that assumption for a couple reasons:

- Table cells, at least by default, don't seem to have a background. This means the drop shadow was applied to the text of the cell in my tests rather than the entire cell.
- It's only `TableRowSkinBase` that does something different to `ListCellSkin` that's potentially relevant to this problem.

That difference mentioned in the second point is a call to `setPickOnBounds(false)`. That isn't called for `ListCell`. Apparently the drop shadow increases the bounds of the cell causing it to overlap its adjacent cells and, since pick-on-bounds is true, that means the mouse hovers over the cell for longer than "expected".

Simply calling `setPickOnBounds(false)` on your custom list cells should fix the issue. For example:

**Main.java**:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    var listView = new ListView<String>();
    listView.getItems().addAll("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");

    listView.setCellFactory(
        lv ->
            new ListCell<>() {

              {
                setPrefHeight(38);
                setPickOnBounds(false); // fix for issue
              }

              @Override
              protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty || item == null) {
                  setText(null);
                } else {
                  setText(item);
                }
              }
            });

    var scene = new Scene(listView, 600, 400);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/test.css").toString());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

**test.css**:

```css
.list-cell:selected:filled:hover {
  -fx-view-order: -1;
  -fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, #67676D, 12, 0.05, 0.0, 2);
}
```

Note: I do not know if calling `setPickOnBounds(false)` causes other issues or not.